# how to get the line where the error : Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client is thrown?

Tags: node.js

As I'm fairly new to Node, i'm unable to know how to debug my code. In coding languages like c++ or python, our compiler tells us the line on which the error is

for ex:

```
    print("Hello World")
    a===a
```

This will result in an error like:

```
'File "main.py", line 2                                                                                                       
    a===a                                                                                                                      
       ^                                                                                                                       
SyntaxError: invalid syntax'
```

but in node I get number of lines as error, like for this case:

```
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:455:11)
at ServerResponse.header (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
at done (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:10)
at tryHandleCache (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:260:5)
at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:485:10)
at View.render (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
at tryRender (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
at Function.render (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
at ServerResponse.render (D:\Node-Tries\22-07-19 to 26-07-19\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

I read a few posts about this error and from what I can tell, it happens if I try to send setheader info after already sending header body information? I am mainly using res.render and res.end in my program, so is there a way to debug the exact line/lines where the extra calls are being made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this code on top of your code

```
Object.defineProperty(global, '__line', {
    get: function(){
        return ((new Error()).stack.split("\n")[2].trim().replace(/^(at\s?)(.*)/gim, "$2 >").replace(__dirname, ""))
    }
})
```

And then use console.log like:

```
console.log(__line, "somthing");
```

it will show you the line number and log

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but can you explain me, do I have to manually add that console.log() at different positions to check if error comes before or after that line? Or is there something else that i'm missing?

Comment: express already showing you where is the error !
`at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:455:11)`

Comment: one more thing use return statement before sending any response:
like `return res.send();`

Comment: well i went ahead and did as I said, manually adding the console log at my intervals and I found where the 2 calls were being made. Thanks for your help.